# filter lines based on set of words in specific column

Tags: text-processing, awk

Having `input.csv` as following:

```
field_name,field_friendly_name
LastNm,Last_Name
cntn_last_mod_wrkr_full_nm,Last_Name
contact_last_nm,Last_Name
contact_first_last_nm,Last_Name
last_english_nm,Last_Name
last_pronunciation_nm,Last_Name
last_nm,Last_Name
lead_space_last_nm,Last_Name
last_mod_usr_nm,Last_Name
lcl_last_nm,Last_Name
adobe_last_topic_nm,Last_Name
last_changed_user_nm,Last_Name
last_purchased_product_service_nm,Last_Name
last_imported_source_nm,Last_Name
submt_last_nm,Last_Name
cntct_last_nm,Last_Name
cust_submt_last_nm,Last_Name
cust_cntct_last_nm,Last_Name
last_mod_by_nm,Last_Name
last_mod_als_nm,Last_Name
last_mod_nm,Last_Name
ship_last_nm,Last_Name
billing_last_nm,Last_Name
last_upd_by_nm,Last_Name
wrkr_last_nm,Last_Name
trns_line_itm_last_chg_psn_nm,Last_Name
trns_line_itm_last_cre_psn_nm,Last_Name
trns_hdr_last_chg_psn_nm,Last_Name
altr_last_nm,Last_Name
trns_last_chg_nm,Last_Name
lastrepaction_nm,Last_Name
last_build_nm,Last_Name
LegalLastNm,Last_Name
ManagerLastNm,Last_Name
4-LastNm,Last_Name
NextLevelManagerLastNm,Last_Name
ManagerLegalLastNm,Last_Name
```

*from this file I would like to filter on column1 where condition is
column1 value should be made of given set of words in this case (last, name, nm, lst, -, _, [0-9] ) and exclude if contains any other words.
And also update column2 as "Found".
And my search should be case insensitive.*

```
LastNm,Found
last_nm,Found
4-LastNm,Found
```

*I'm using this way wchich doesn't work:*

```
awk -v q="'" --field-separator ',' '((tolower($1) ~ /last/) && (tolower($1) ~ /name/)) || ((tolower($1) ~ /last/) && (tolower($1) ~ /nm/)) && ($2="found") {print $1 "," $2  }' raw.csv
```

Comment: @αғsнιη can you re-post your answer plz

Comment: my commamd was `awk -F, '
BEGIN{ IGNORECASE=1; split("last|name|nm|lst|-|_|[0-9]", words, "|") }
     { len=RLENGTH=0; for (x in words){ if (match($1,words[x])) len+=RLENGTH; };
       if (len==length($1)) { $2="found"; print };
}' OFS=, infile`, however [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/593771/72456) is your best choice

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With GNU `awk`, `gensub` could be used to remove all those words, print if empty:

```
awk -F , -v OFS=, 'gensub(/last|lst|name|nm|[0-9_-]*/,"","g",tolower($1))=="" {
    $2="found";
    print $1, $2
}' file
```

Unlike `sub`/`gsub`, `gensub` leaves the original record intact and instead returns the resulting string. The same approach could be used with standard `awk` by copying field into a variable.

To include more characters than `[0-9_-]`, you could use `[^[:alpha:]]` (i.e. `anything that isn't a letter`):

```
last|lst|name|nm|[^[:alpha:]]
```

Comment: Using `[^a-zA-Z]` or `[^[:alpha:]]` instead of `[0-9_-]` would make it a bit more robust if there are more characters to be excluded between words.

Comment: @guest "","g"  what is the use of this ?

Comment: `gensub(pattern,replacement,modifiers)`. This replaces pattern with empty string, with modifier **g**lobally (=do not stop after first match).

Comment: i do not want to replace with empty string; I've a big file running this code getting something else like,found
,found
,found
,found
,found
,found
,found
,found
,found
,found
,found   `awk -F , -v OFS=, 'gensub(/last|lst|name|nm|[0-9_-]*/,"","g",tolower($1))=="" {
    $2="found";
    print $1, $2
}' raw2.csv | wc -l `
144

Comment: Then you're not running that code. The replacement is only for the comparison, it does not overwrite anything.

Comment: but still column1 is omitting in my output

Comment: thank you all, its working as expected, input csv file had quotes enclosed on each of values and hence this code wasn't working

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '
{
split($1,w,/[^[:alnum:]]/);
for (i in w) {
    if (!(match(tolower(w[i]),/\<([0-9]*|last|nm|name|lastnm|lastname)\>/))) next;
}
$2="Found"; print; 
}' file
```

Output:

```
LastNm,Found
last_nm,Found
4-LastNm,Found
```

Explanation:

- `split` field `$1` by all not (`[^.]`) alphanumeric (`[:alnum:]`) characters to get list of words.
- `for` loop over these words.
- if a word does **not** match the given regex holding the allowed words, jump to `next` record.
- if that did not happen, we can finally assign `$2="Found"` and `print` the record